# Android Handling Mediaplayer

Tags: android

I have created an application that I used about 44 short audio records. 
For each I have created a button. But, sometimes the sound of a specific button doesn't work.

How can I fix it
I will post a part of the code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first__window);
    play_1= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.a1);
    play_2= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.a2);
    play_3= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.a3);
    play_4= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.a4);
  }
  public void btn_1(View view)
{
    play_1.start();
}

public void btn_2(View view)
{
    play_2.start();
}

public void btn_3(View view)
{
    play_3.start();
}

public void btn_4(View view)
{
    play_4.start(); 
 }
```

I don't know if I have to add some functions to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onClick Listener to such a manner. 
You can do the followings :

```
btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
play_2= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.a1);
play_2.start();
while(play_2.isPlaying()) ; 
play_2.release();
} 
});
```